# How to compare between rows in a same column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list, list-validation

I working on to have a validation on a SharePoint list. One of the requirement is in Column A it should **not contain serial number** which are the numbers that in a manner only differ +1 from one another.

For example in column A:

WS22288906**15**

WS22288906**16**

WS22288906**17**

WS22288906**18**

WS7725700677

WS5825890658

In this example, the number in top 4 rows only differ +1 and should return error in validation.

I have found a way to extract separately the number from the character. But still need help on how to compare the different between rows to detect the +1 different and return error.

Hope to have a help form the community. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On new/edit form you can write custom javascript. And use `PreSaveAction` function. In this function you can use your custom valudation code (i.e. get existing data from list and compare with the current value and all.....)

Comment: And the 2nd way is to write event receiver. As you are using using SharePoint-Online you will have to write a Remote-Event Receiver to achieve this.  This will require to setup app environment and all..

Comment: @RohitWaghela ,on new-->edit form, then I just get 'edit column' and 'customize with PowerApps' option. In edit column option I just able to rearrange the column arrange ment up and down in the form. Could you please explain where I can writet he custom java script?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, you may need to use a event receiver to query all the list items for the specific column and check if there are items have the filed value in the range (new value ± 1). Column validation or calculated column will not be able to help you.